# Macro for file's directory in Intelij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style

am trying to change the working directory to FIle's Directory instead of Modules Directory in IntelliJ.
i.e, if I have A(module)->B>C>temp.java, when I try to run the temp.java file, the working directory should change to A/B/C.
i there a macro stored in Intelij similar to $ProjectFileDir$/ $Module_Dir$.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

File name is not available in the run configuration context. You are running a class from the classpath, not a source .java file from the source directory, therefore there is no way to specify the directory of the .java file in the run configuration, it simply doesn't know which .java file you are running (as you are actually running a compiled class).

Comment: is there a workaround or a hack for the same?

Comment: Why do you need to set the working directory to the location of the source .java file? If your code reads a file from the file system, change it to read the file from the classpath instead and place it into the resources directory, this way you will not need to specify the working directory or the absolute file path and your code will be more portable.